# What is the lifecycle of @State variables in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I create a new `@State` variable, when does it get destroyed? Does it live for the lifetime of the parent `UIHostingController`?

As far as I can find, it is not documented. This is relevant because I don't understand how to clean up after myself if I create an `ObservableObject` as `State` somewhere in the view hierarchy.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Example: View {
    @State private var foo = Foo()
    var body: some View {
        Text("My Great View")
    }
}

class Foo: ObservableObject {
    deinit {
        // When will this happen?
        print("Goodbye!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not much familiar with `state` or `SwiftUI`, but isn't just based on the type of `Foo` ie if it's _reference_ type then whenever its retain count is moved down to zero. If it's a _variable_ types, then you really don't care about their lifecycles.

Comment: The question is about _when_, if ever, that variable will be `deinit`ed in SwiftUI.

Comment: Putting `ObservableObject` as `State` is at least misconception, it must be paired with `ObservedObject`. Moreover... property wrapper State (and ObservedObject) is struct, value type.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In iOS 14, the proper way to do this is to use `@StateObject`. There is no safe way to store a reference type in `@State`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

```
struct Example: View {
    @State private var foo = Foo()
    var body: some View {
        Text("My Great View")
    }
}

class Foo: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        print(#function)
    }
    deinit {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

The issue is that a `View` type is a `struct`, and it's `body` is not a collection of functions that are executed in real-time but actually initialized at the same time when `View`'s `body` is rendered.

#### Problem Scenario:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Example()) {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you notice, `Example.init` is called before the navigation even occurs, and on pop `Example.deinit` isn't called at all. The reason for this is that when `ContentView` is initialized, it has to initialize everything in it's `body` as well. So `Example.init` **will** be called.

When we navigate to `Example`, it was already initialized so `Example.init` is not called again. When we pop out of `Example`, we just go back to `ContentView` but since `Example` might be needed again, and since it is not created in real-time, it is not destroyed.

`Example.deinit` will be called only when `ContentView` has to be removed entirely.

I wasn't sure on this but found another article talking about a similar issue here:

- [SwiftUI and How NOT to Initialize Bindable Objects](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-101-how-not-to-initialize-bindable-objects-6e539d1b5344)

To prove this, lets ensure the `ContentView` is being completely removed.
The following example makes use of an action sheet to present and remove it from the view hierarchy.

#### Working Scenario:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.isPresented.toggle() }) {
            Text("Test")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Example()
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isPresented.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

PS: This applies to classes even if not declared as `@State`, and does not really have anything to do with `ObservableObject`.

Comment: "So when the View is gone, so is the variable."

This isn't true in my testing though, that `deinit` in my example never gets called.

Comment: @WilGieseler Ok, will take a look in a playground test

Comment: @WilGieseler I was able to have `deinit` called but I had to make sure the `View` is being removed. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Your answer uses `private var foo = Foo()` not `@State private var foo = Foo()`, which I think might be the crux of the issue?

Comment: Ugh, no maybe not, I'm trying to figure out an issue involving `@State` and `@Observable` object but it is hard to simplify the repro. Still trying...

Comment: @WilGieseler Sorry, that was my copy-paste typo. I was looking at class lifecycle with and without `@State`, and both have `deinit` called when `View` is removed entirely. But not when the `View` is still a part of the heirarchy.

Comment: @WilGieseler Btw, what are you exactly trying to figure out? the case is same even without using `@State` and `@ObservableObject`. So the cause probably lies elsewhere in the `SwiftUI` inner workings

Comment: @WilGieseler I confirmed my suspicions and have updated the answer with a reference link. The issue is that the `View` is a `struct` and `body` is not a collection of functions that is executed at real-time.